# Kendo UI Checkbox unclicable

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

Checkboxes when using `class="k-checkbox"` are unclickable. They are clickable if those classes ommited.

```
<script id="user-groups-li-edit" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="#:data.id#" id="#:data.id#" class="k-checkbox" # if (data.checked) { # checked # } #>
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="#:data.id#">#:data.nazwa#</label>
    </li>
</script>


<script id="document-edit-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div id="document-groups">
        <ul class="fieldlist-groups" data-role="listview"
            data-template="user-groups-li-edit"
            data-bind="source: groupsData">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
      var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
          read: {
            url: API_URL+"getusergroups/"+id,
            dataType: "json"
          }
        }
      });

      var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        groupsData: dataSource,
      });

      kendo.bind($("\#document-groups"), viewModel);
      <\/script>
</script>
```

Comment: U might be missing some libraries. check [Your line of code work fine here](https://dojo.telerik.com/ERURaxag)

Comment: Libraries are in. Kendo checkboxes working in this page, outside grid edit popup.